# How to get index of spsecific values in list - python

Tags: python, arrays, list, indexing

If I have a list:

```
A = [1,1,1,0,0,1,0]
```

How can I return the index of any occurence of the number 1?

With this example, how to return the following:

```
[0, 1, 2, 5]
```

This is because the number 1 appears specifically in these parts of the list

Comment: `[i for i, x in enumerate(A) if x == 1]`

Comment: I think Pedro Maia's answer is the one I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a simple list comprehension:

```py
A = [1,1,1,0,0,1,0]

i = [i for i,v in enumerate(A) if v==1]
```

```
[0, 1, 2, 5]
```

Comment: Could you provide an explanation for how enumerate works here? Is it sort of like a second index?

Comment: It creates a list of `tuples` with each element and its associated index e.g. `enumerate([1,2,2,3])` would become `[(0,1),(1,2),(2,2),(3,3)]` the first number is the index and the second is the value. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)

Comment: How would this look in a function without enumerate?

Comment: You'd need to iterate over the range of the len: `i = [i for i in range(len(A)) if A[i]==1]`